# Set vertical rulers in vscode based on file type?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wish to set the following rulers only when viewing *.py files. Is that possible?

```
{
    "editor.rulers": [72, 79]
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As of [version 1.9](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_language-specific-settings), Language specific settings was introduced. This means that you can now use the following configuration to achieve what you want:

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.rulers": [72, 79]
}
```

Comment: How do you set a default to be used if the file type is not of the type specified?

Comment: @joe_04_04 I would assume one simply adds `"editor.rulers": [72, 79]` to `settings.json`, not inside a language-specific tag.

Comment: To get the correct language to put in `[<language>]`, use VS Code's **[Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings)** command and then select the language from the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

It looks they have recently added support to have different settings for notebooks. Adding the following to my settings.json has done the trick of adding the rulers to my .py files, but removing them from .ipynb, for example.

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.rulers": [79, 120]
},
"notebook.editorOptionsCustomizations":{
    "editor.rulers": []
}
```