# How do I set up VSCode settings so that rules are different for different file types?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my VSCode user settings, I have a default ruler at 80 chars using:

```
"editor.rulers": [80],
```

When editing git commits — to assist in adhering to the 50/72 rule ([1](https://medium.com/@preslavrachev/what-s-with-the-50-72-rule-8a906f61f09c), [2](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/#seven-rules)) — I'd like to override the default with the following rulers:

```
"editor.rulers": [50, 72],
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806241/set-vertical-rulers-in-vscode-based-on-file-type)...

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings  [git-commit]

Answer (score 2):

Given the comments on my question above, I have a working solution:

```json
{
  "editor.rulers": [80],
  "[git-commit]": {
    "editor.rulers": [50, 72]
  },
}
```

More info on [VSCode Language specific editor settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings)