# Make vertical rulers invisible in .ipynb - files in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, settings

In my settings.json, I have

```
    "[python]": {
    "editor.rulers": [
        79,
        120
    ],
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
},
```

but these rulers also appear in all my Jupyter Notebooks, which is not desired.

[image: rulers in vertical notebook]

How can I make these exempt from showing the rulers?

**PS:**
In the main articles regarding rulers, nothing like that has been answered till now:

- [Vertical rulers in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code)
- [Set vertical rulers in vscode based on file type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806241/set-vertical-rulers-in-vscode-based-on-file-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this has finally been implemented. Adding the following to my settings.json has done the trick of adding the rulers to my .py files, but removing them from .ipynb, for example.

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.rulers": [79, 120]
},
"notebook.editorOptionsCustomizations":{
    "editor.rulers": []
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this workaround is good enough, better than nothing!

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid it's impossible for now. I had submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18843) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, let's see how quickly this will be implemented.